# Is it possible to create a Q# operation with optional parameters?

Tags: programming, q#

In C# it is possible to have:

```
public void Fun (int n = 0){
    // ...
}
```

then the following method call examples will be compiled:

- `Fun()`
- `Fun(10)`

So I wonder whether or not such a useful facility is available in creating Q# operations with optional parameters?

Comment: If you want to make this a feature request, please go on and file it as an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment. As of version 0.10, Q# doesn't support optional parameters, and it does not allow to define two operations with the same name that would only differ by the list of parameters (which would be a different way to do the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

One way that I've found that works pretty well is to define a new UDT for options, and then provide a function that returns a reasonable set of defaults. For instance, in the case you gave, you might have something like:

```
newtype FunOptions = (
   N : Int,
   SomeOtherOption : Double[]
);

function DefaultFunOptions() : FunOptions {
    return (0, [0.0]);
}

function Fun(options : FunOptions) : Double {
    // do something using options::N and options::SomeOtherOption
}
```

This lets you call `Fun` by using the `w/` to provide optional arguments as you see fit:

```
let w = Fun(DefaultFunOptions());
let x = Fun(DefaultFunOptions() w/ N <- 10);
let y = Fun(DefaultFunOptions() w/ SomeOtherOption <- [0.1, 0.2]);
let z = Fun(DefaultFunOptions() w/ N <- 42 w/ SomeOtherOption <- [0.1, 0.2]);
```

This is the approach taken, for instance, with the new quantum machine learning library currently under development. If you're interested, check out the pull request where the new `TrainingOptions` UDT was first introduced at https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/pull/187.

Comment: I haven't run your solution on my machine yet, but I should thank you for this creative approach to the question!